# Connect external swf button to main timeline

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a newbie on Actionscipt 3.0 and I am looking for a little help. I would like to know how to connect  the button from my external swf file to my main timeline. Thanks :]

Comment: i tried loading an external swf with button inside it to go to my desired frame on my main timeline. but I cannot access that frame :]

Comment: Assuming the loader context isn't blocking the swf from access,  you can use the `root` keyword.   `MovieClip(root).nextFrame();`

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a bad idea due to memory management and null references.  Regardless...

Consider the following layout:

```
Stage
    0:MainTimeline
        0:RandomMovieClip
        1:Loader
            0:ExternalSWF
                0:Button
```

You could reference it relatively, by pathing up from Button's location...

```
Button.parent.parent.parent.goToAndPlay("MyFrame");
```

Or absolutely, from the stage...

```
stage.getChildAt(0).goToAndPlay("MyFrame");
```

Be aware that `Button.root` is not the same as `RandomMovieClip.root`.  The first is pointing to your `ExternalSWF`, while the latter refers to `MainTimeline` just below Stage.

Alternatively, you could create event listeners on the button from the parent timeline.

```
// This is just a general idea of loading an swf.
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_complete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("external.swf"));
addChild(loader);

function loader_complete(e:Event):void {
    // Once loaded, path down to the button, and add an event listener to it.
    var loaderRef:Loader = e.currentTarget.loader as Loader;
    var extSWFRef:MainTimeline = loaderRef.getChildAt(0) as MovieClip;
    var myButton == extSWFRef.getChildByName("MyButton");

    myButton.addEventListener("click", buttonHandler);
}

function buttonHandler(e:Event):void {
    trace("It worked!")
}
```

Just be mindful of the event, and be sure to remove the listener before unloading the child swf.